# how do I subtract 16 characters from the end of the output?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program where you encrypt a piece of data and then subtract the last 16 characters from the output.

```
import hashlib

# initializing string
str2hash = "test" #input

# encoding GeeksforGeeks using encode()
# then sending to md5()
result = hashlib.md5(str2hash.encode())
# printing the equivalent hexadecimal value.
print("The hexadecimal equivalent of hash is : ", end="")
print(result.hexdigest())
```

some stuff that I've tried are

```
print(result.hexdigest()) -16
```

```
 str2hash = "test" -16
```

I'm pretty new to coding in python so any help I can get from this will help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Depends what you mean by "repeats"

You are hashing 51 times, and only (trying to) remove the last 16 characters 50 times. Is that what you intended?

Secondly, as @B Remmelzwaal points out, you are only printing the reduced string, not saving it.

Try replacing

```
print(string_result[:-16])
```

with

```
string_result = string_result[:-16]
```

But *do* check how many times you actually need to do each thing.

Answer (score 0):

Given my previous comment and what @Eureka suggested, this would be your fixed code:

```py
import hashlib

str2hash = 'MjhjMmRmMTIzMWFlOWVkMA=='
result = str2hash

for _ in range(50):
    result = str(hashlib.md5(result.encode()).hexdigest())[:-16]

print(result)
```

Output:

```py
7675a9ba7938ca55
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing). Specifically, a "stop" index of `-16` indicates that you wish to stop 16 characters before the end of the string.

```
print(result[:-16])
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your result result.hexdigest() is a string you can simply get all elements except the last 16 by slicing from the end:

```
    h = result.hexdigest()[:-16]
```

Here, -16 is 16 characters from the end and : denotes all characters before that.